# Unable to install Unity Revamped --ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped

Tags: 12.04, unity

I intend to use a forked version of unity (ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped) over the original one. The problem I'm facing is that the forked version is 5.12.0-0ubuntu3 and the original one is 5.14.0-0ubuntu1.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

using the above commands gives me the following output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Calculating upgrade... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any help ?

Links

https://launchpad.net/~ikarosdev/+archive/unity-revamped

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/unity/5.14.0-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found why it's not working for you.  `5.14.0-0ubuntu1` is still in the proposed section of the software repositories.  If you disable the proposed selection in the software sources and then run the install commands it should then give you the option of installing `unity-revamped`

Open the Software Center and in the **Edit** menu select software sources then click on the updates tab....

[image]

Remove the check from the **Proposed** box.

Then in a terminal run

`sudo apt-get update`
After the update is completed try to run

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again and it should show you that unity `5.12.0-0ubuntu3` is available.

Just a note, it is safer to not select the **Proposed** updates unless you need some program that is not available in the current release.  The **Proposed** selection will install as updates all the newest programs, **but** they are the programs that are still in the testing phase so they can have some bugs still.  Once the programs that are in the **Proposed** section have been fully tested, they will be moved to the **Updates** section and be available as a stable package.

The `untiy-revamped` ppa lags behind the release a little bit, I believe that it was about a week the last time but he seems to do a good job of keeping it updated(as far as I can tell anyway, this ppa has only been running a short time)

As an aside, I have been running `unity-revamped` and have had very few problems with it, the **dodge windows** feature occasionally sticks and will not hide the launcher but it is fixed by logging out and back in.  This only happens once in a great while and everything else works fine while it is stuck....

---

Edit:  the above mentioned version of unity (`5.14.0-0ubuntu1`) is currently the recent version of unity so `5.14.0-0ubuntu1+ikarosdev2` should install correctly (as of Sept 2012) but this answer will still work if you have the `proposed` repository selected and are getting a similar error but with different version numbers.  i.e. this will occur any time a new version of `Unity` is installed from the proposed section but the `unity-revamped` ppa has not bee updated to the newest "proposed" version.

Comment: @EmersonHsieh sorry to step on your answer, I would have just added this as a comment but it was too complicated to squeeze into a comment...

Comment: Thankyou TrailRider, your solution worked like a charm!. I first unchecked the Proposed updates in software sources, then had to purge the unity-revamped PPA and added it again. At last updated and upgraded. Thank you, for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: glad I could help, your problem threw me for a loop, I had to search for the version of unity you _had_ installed to figure out that it was in the proposed section, then it started to make some sense.

Comment: I can't thankyou enough for all the trouble you took for finding me a solution. Keep up the awesome work bro.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sudo apt-get upgrade` with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

`sudo apt-get upgrade` updates installed packages and never installs new packages.

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` updates installed packages, and may install new packages along the way.

Comment: +1 in fact [OmgUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/enable-dodge-unity-launcher-ubuntu-12-04) says to use the `dist-upgrade` command in their instructions on how to install it.

Comment: I had tried that too, returns with:  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded