# Unable to install Unity Revamped (ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped)

Tags: unity, launcher, ppa, minimize

I intend to use a forked version of unity (ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped) over the original one. The problem I'm facing is that the forked version is 5.18.0-0ubuntu1 and the original one is 5.18.0-0ubuntu2. I do:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The PPA is added successfully. The output from the last two commands is:

```
jon@lemur:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
jon@lemur:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Apparently nothing got updated. I rebooted and the unity launcher minimize-on-click functionality wasn't there.

I found [Unable to install Unity Revamped](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169715/unable-to-install-unity-revamped-ppaikarosdev-unity-revamped), and followed the accepted answer. I already had the check in 'Pre-released updates (precise-proposed)' removed.

Any help?

#### Edit 1:

[smartboyhw](https://askubuntu.com/users/84117/smartboyhw) suggested this:

```
sudo apt-get install unity=5.18.0-0ubuntu1
```

but it only resulted in:

```
jon@lemur:~$ sudo apt-get install unity=5.18.0-0ubuntu1
[sudo] password for jon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '5.18.0-0ubuntu1' for 'unity' was not found
```

which is a bit weird, as y-ppa (a PPA management app that I have installed) tells me that the package '5.18.0-0ubuntu1' is indeed in my ikarosdev/unity-revamped PPA.

#### Edit 2:

[gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/users/88802/gertvdijk) requested output from `apt-cache policy unity`:

```
jon@lemur:~$ apt-cache policy unity
unity:
  Installed: 5.18.0-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.18.0-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.18.0-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.18.0-0ubuntu1+ikarosdev1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ikarosdev/unity-revamped/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     5.10.0-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

I am on Ubuntu **12.04**

#### Links

[https://launchpad.net/~ikarosdev/+archive/unity-revamped](https://launchpad.net/%7Eikarosdev/+archive/unity-revamped)
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/unity/5.18.0-0ubuntu1

Comment: Could you provide the output of `apt-cache policy unity` in your question? And are you on 12.04 or 12.10? Because that PPA only builds for 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

The version in PPA is 5.18.0-0ubuntu1 while the version in the official repositories is 5.18.0-0ubuntu2. That means the version in the official repositories is newer than in the PA. That's why using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or `sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't work.

You should first install the 5.18.0-0ubuntu1 version by using `sudo apt-get install unity=5.18.0-0ubuntu1` then remove the newest Unity (5.18.0-0ubuntu2) by doing `sudo apt-get remove unity=5.18.0-0ubuntu2`

Comment: Do you think the PPA owner will update the PPA to accomodate the new version of Unity, soonish? In other words: can I expect it to fix itself if I just wait?

Comment: If you just have the newest version of Unity in repos you don't necessarily have to wait for it in PPA... You already have the latest using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @smartboyhw This PPA provides a *modified* version of Unity - OP probably wants this instead of the latest updated version. And moreover, I think downgrading in the first step (`install unity=...`) will already remove the newer version. My best guess is that the latest `apt-get remove` step will not be needed and only result in errors.